Base de datos MYSQL
tengo que crear un programa en netbeans con base de datos, cuando quiero probar la conexión me figura lo de la imagen y no se como solucionarlo ya que es la primera vez que lo estoy ultilizando por ende no tengo idea de contraseña

Podes encontrar la respuesta en este mismo post

El mensaje que te está enviando es que root requiere contraseña, por favor revisa los datos de tu conexión. ¿Una pregunta estás usando  mysql de forma independiente?

Buenas, Agostina, pero para conectarte tienes que tener instalado y arrancado un servidor MySql en tu máquina local. Cuando se instala dicho servidor, el propio wizard te pregunta qué clave quieres establecer.

Pon siempre tanto el texto como los mensajes de error como texto, con formato, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, pon un título descriptivo a tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
